# Python3.6 ImportError when running script outside the directory. Runs correctly within same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following set up.

```
~/python/pyct/lib/
├── printer.py
└── utils.py

~/apps/proj/
└── main.py
```

**~/python/pyct/lib/utils.py**

```
def printFunc(content):
    print(content)
```

**~/python/pyct/lib/printer.py**

```
import utils  # this breaks sometimes
# import pyct.lib.utils as utils # this works always

def printer(content):
    utils.printFunc(content)
```

**~/apps/proj/main.py**

```
from pyct.lib.printer import printer
printer("hi")
```

Value of `PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python`

When I import `printer.py` in a file inside `~/python/pyct/lib/`, everything runs as expected.

When I run `main.py` from `~/apps/proj/`, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyct.lib.printer import printer
  File "~/python/pyct/lib/printer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

I have tried using relative imports but that doesn't work. I have gone through [this](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-init-py-trap) resource but could get the scenario working.

I am aware that the problem can be solved using absolute path in imports but I want to make a dir with multiple python files which will act as a library. Then use the core component else where outside the directory.

How can I achive the above scenario working. 
Any resources to understand python imports will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `~/python/pyct/lib/printer.py` looks for module named `utils` in its working directory - not in directory where it is placed itself.

You can use relative import in **~/python/pyct/lib/printer.py**:

```
from . import utils
```

python will then look for module relative to the path of the importing one instead of working directory.

Comment: Thanks. This worked like charm. I overlooked importing module this way. I used to import only functions/classes using from statements.